# Analyzing Percentages of Grades Over the Years

Tags: distributions

I found a previous question such as this, however it was unanswered.  I have some data on distributions of grades over the years for a class (ex. 2011 - 45% A, 40% B, 3% C, 2% D/F, 2012 - 40% A... and so on).  I'm trying to think of the most appropriate way to analyze this, trying to examine how grade trends have changed throughout the years.  Is it as simple as an ANOVA, how about assumptions and dealing with % data?  Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Second to last sentence is unclear to me. My first thought is 'quantile regression'

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I apologize for the unclear language.  Given the fact that the data is in percentages, and the number of students changes over the years...I didn't know what kind of issues that might bring up with normality and appropriate statistical analyses

Answer (score 1):

You question is 'how to examine....' Start by plotting A's over time, then B's etc. What this looks like will determine what else you can do with the data.